# MSSQL - Use hierarchical query result as subquery

Tags: sql-server, select, tree, hierarchical-data

i want to use  hierarchical query result as subquery but i get some errors:
My hierarchical query:

```
   select * from (WITH tree (Oid, name, level) AS ( SELECT Oid, Name, 1 as level FROM Company 
                where Oid='20C269DE-A15F-48B3-AFC2-47FBF53C1EAE' and GCRecord is null 
                UNION ALL SELECT child.Oid, child.name, parent.level + 1 FROM Company as child 
                JOIN tree parent on parent.Oid = child.ParentCompany where child.GCRecord is null ) SELECT Oid FROM tree) t
```

And my problematic query as below:

```
select  *from DeliverySchedule where Company in ( 
WITH tree (Oid, name, level) AS ( SELECT Oid, Name, 1 as level FROM Company 
                where Oid='20C269DE-A15F-48B3-AFC2-47FBF53C1EAE' and GCRecord is null 
                UNION ALL SELECT child.Oid, child.name, parent.level + 1 FROM Company as child 
                JOIN tree parent on parent.Oid = child.ParentCompany where child.GCRecord is null ) SELECT Oid FROM tree)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
;with tree ( Oid , name , level ) as (
  select Oid
    , name
    , 1 as level
  from Company
  where Oid = '20C269DE-A15F-48B3-AFC2-47FBF53C1EAE' 
    and GCRecord is null
 union all
 select 
      child.Oid
    , child.name
    , parent.level + 1
  from Company as child
    inner join tree parent 
      on parent.Oid = child.ParentCompany
  where child.GCRecord is null
)

select * 
from DeliverySchedule 
where Company in (select Oid from tree);
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance